# How can I ask someone about touchpad standards?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, deleted-questions, specific-question

How can I ask a question about touchpad standards?

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13995/7842

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [help center](/help). You can't; questions about standards are off-topic here.